# SQL Server 2012 reduce bit values if exists

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Here is my example and my requirement. I am using SQL Server 2012.

```
declare @nMyBitValue bigint = 32

update MyTabl1
set MyBitValue = case
                    when MyBitValue & @nMyBitValue <> 0 
                       then MyBitValue - @nMyBitValue
                       else MyBitValue
                 end
where Id = 1
```

Existing data in column `MyBitValue` is 48, `@nMyBitValue = 32`.

Now if 32 value exists in `MyBitValue`, then this value should be reduced from `MyBitValue` column.

I have reduced my value by `MyBitValue - @nMyBitValue`. But is there any other way to reduce my value?

Comment: Are you using SQL Server 2012 or MySQL?

Comment: SQL Server 2012

Comment: Your requirement is unclear to me! - As I see: You want to update `MyBitValue` field when it is equal to `@nMyBitValue` to `0` !, Is this that? ;)

Comment: Your code is like this: `update MyTabl1 set MyBitValue=MyBitValue-@nMyBitValue where Id = 1 AND MyBitValue & @nMyBitValue <> 0` ;).

Comment: No my requirement is when 32 exits then remove 32 from existing total value

Comment: Delete From MyTabl1 Where MyBitValue = 32 and Id = 1 ?

Comment: column values can be like 2 power 0, 2 power 1....so on suppose if my existing column value is 48 that is nothing but 2 power 0 + 2 power 1 + 2 power 2 + 2 power 3 + 2 power 4 + (2 power 0 + 2 power 1 + 2 power 2 + 2 power 3 + 2 power 4 + 2 power 5) ie 16+32

Comment: No i shouldnt check based on MyBitValue value i need to check on id and i need apply my update logic to that column and should'nt delete that row

Comment: I edit your question and change _remove_ to _reduce_, If it's not what you want, you can roll it back ;).

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, No; I think there is not a better way to do this, but you can optimize your code like this:

```
declare @nMyBitValue bigint = 32;

update MyTabl1
set MyBitValue = MyBitValue & ~@nMyBitValue
 -- MyBitValue - @nMyBitValue  -->> I thought this is better 
where Id = 1 
  and MyBitValue & @nMyBitValue <> 0;
```

This will update only rows those need to update not all rows of `Id =1`

Comment: I am asking instead of removing directly using substract operator is there any other way to remove that value

Comment: And I answered , No ;).

Comment: You have set it directly like this MyBitValue-@nMyBitValue, but i should'nt use "-"

Comment: So you can use `p - q` equality of `p & ~q`, But it is more complex and slower ;).

Answer (score 0):

Try below update query

```
 DECLARE @nMyBitValue bigint = 32

 UPDATE MyTabl1 
 SET MyBitValue = CASE WHEN ( MyBitValue > 0 AND @nMyBitValue > 0 )
                       THEN MyBitValue - @nMyBitValue ELSE MyBitValue END
 WHERE Id = 1
```

Comment: i should'nt remove directly using "-" operator. Is there any other way to reduce?

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution

```
 declare @nMyBitValue bigint = 32

 update MyTabl1
     set MyBitValue = 
        case
          when MyBitValue & @nMyBitValue <> 0 then MyBitValue ^ @nMyBitValue
          else MyBitValue
        end
     where Id = 1
```